# Read non-ASCII MS Access database (Punjabi text using Gurmukhi (ਗੁਰਮੁਖੀ) alphabet) in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, ms-access, character-encoding, non-ascii-characters

I have a Microsoft Access database which contains columns in Punjabi language using using Gurmukhi (ਗੁਰਮੁਖੀ) script. When I read the database in MATLAB the Punjabi words are displayed as `?????`.

How can I read in the data correctly? 
here is the code:

```matlab
slCharacterEncoding('UTF-8');

setdbprefs('DataReturnFormat', 'cellarray');

setdbprefs('NullNumberRead', 'NaN');

setdbprefs('NullStringRead', 'null');

%Make connection to database. Note that the password has been omitted. 

conn = database('Punjabi', '', '');

%Read data from database. 


curs = exec(conn, ['SELECT DICWEB2.ID'... ' ,   DICWEB2.gur'...

    ' , DICWEB2.Meaning'...
    ' , DICWEB2.Shah'...
    ' , DICWEB2.Type'...
    ' , DICWEB2.sFile'...
    ' FROM  DICWEB2 ']);
curs = fetch(curs);
close(curs);

%Assign data to output variable


Pun1 = curs.Data;

%Close database connection.

close(conn);

%Clear variables

clear curs conn
```

[image: Here is snap shot of problem]

Comment: what if you use this command before loading the database: `feature('DefaultCharacterSet', 'UTF8')`?

Comment: Do you know the encoding used in the data? Is it one of the Unicode Encodings, possibly `UTF8` or `UTF16`? Or is it 8bit ASCII with a Punjabi-specific code-page?

Comment: I don't know whether it matters for the solution. (It might if code-pages are involved.) ... Is the data in [Gurmukhi (ਗੁਰਮੁਖੀ) alphabet or Shahmukhi (شاہ مکھی) alphabet](http://www.omniglot.com/writing/punjabi.htm)? (Sorry, by Browser seems to drop the RTL control characters when pasting.)

Comment: @das-g the data is gurmukhi format.

Comment: Uh, **edit** your question and put the code there, please. In a comment it's not really legible, as all line breaks are lost.

Comment: Thanks. :-) I've marked it up as a code block for you. (Review pending.)

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar problem for **Persian** language. It's simple :

1. Go to **Control Panel > Region > Administrative** and change *Language for non-unicode programs*
2. Select *Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support*
3. Run `feature('DefaultCharacterSet', 'UTF-8');` in Matlab